# R Bar Graph Changes

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make the following changes to the graph:

(1) I would like a title for the graph that is centered. When I try adding a title, it is on the left side.

(2) I would like the y-axis label to have more than one word. Namely "Average (Per Game)". Every time I have more than one word, the graph completely changes. I would also like "Average" and "(Per Game)" to be on different lines, if that is possible.

(3) I would like the background of the graph to be gray, but with white grid lines.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
df <- read.table(textConnection(
  'Statistic  Warm Avg Cold
  HR(Away) 1.151 1.028 .841
  HR(Home) 1.202 1.058 .949
  BB(Away) 3.205 3.269 3.481
  BB(Home) 3.286 3.367 3.669
  Runs(Away) 4.909 4.591 4.353
  Runs(Home) 5.173 4.739 4.608'), header = TRUE)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>% 
  gather(Temperature, Average, -Statistic) %>% 
  mutate(Temperature = factor(Temperature, c("Cold", "Avg", "Warm"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Statistic, y=Average)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = Temperature), position = "dodge") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "yellow", "red"))+ 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 0.5))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) To center the title add `plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)` to the theme

(2) Add `labs(y = "Average\n(Per game)")` to add a label for the y axis. The "\n" breaks the line.

(3) Easiest solution is to remove `theme_bw`. Alternatively, check out http://docs.ggplot2.org/dev/vignettes/themes.html

```
df <- read.table(textConnection(
  'Statistic  Warm Avg Cold
  HR(Away) 1.151 1.028 .841
  HR(Home) 1.202 1.058 .949
  BB(Away) 3.205 3.269 3.481
  BB(Home) 3.286 3.367 3.669
  Runs(Away) 4.909 4.591 4.353
  Runs(Home) 5.173 4.739 4.608'), header = TRUE)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>% 
  gather(Temperature, Average, -Statistic) %>% 
  mutate(Temperature = factor(Temperature, c("Cold", "Avg", "Warm"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Statistic, y=Average)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Temperature), stat='identity', position = "dodge") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "yellow", "red"))+ 
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 0.5),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +   
  labs(title = "Title", y = "Average\n(Per game)")
```

Comment: Thank you! It looks just how I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

NBATreands' answer is perfect, and this is my answer:

```
df %>% 
  gather(Temperature, Average, -Statistic) %>% 
  mutate(Temperature = factor(Temperature, c("Cold", "Avg", "Warm"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Statistic, y=Average)) +
  ggtitle("This is the title") +
  ylab("Average\n(Per game)") +
  geom_col(aes(fill = Temperature), position = "dodge") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "yellow", "red"))+ 
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5),
    axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 0.5),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "gray"),
    panel.grid = element_line(colour = "white")
    )
```

The result plot is :
[image]

Comment: I like the darker shade of gray in the background!